# Choose the "smallest" basis of a set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, np-complete

First: I know that every basis of some vector space contains the same amount of vectors. The question is not about that.

Let $\vec a_1, \dots, \vec a_m \in \mathbb{N}^n \setminus \{\vec 0\}$ be some vectors. And I want to select a basis $\vec b_1, \dots, \vec b_r \in \{\vec a_1, \dots, \vec a_m\}$ of the span of $\vec a_1, \dots, \vec a_m$. This is a trivial task and can be done using some Gauß elimination steps. But, I want the basis to have a very special property:

For each vector $\vec a_j, j\in [m]$ we find a linear combination of the basis vectors:
$$\vec a_j = \sum_{i=1}^r \lambda_i \cdot \vec b_i \qquad \mathrm{with}\quad \lambda_i \in \mathbb{Q}$$
I want to choose the basis in such a way that for every $\vec a_j$ it will hold that
$$\sum_{i=1}^r \lambda_i \stackrel{!}{\geq} 1$$
I hope you can see, why I call that basis the "smallest" possible basis. We need the coefficiants to at least add up to 1 to reach all other vectors. Does there always exist such a basis? How can you find it?

While researching and thinking about this problem, I stumbled upon some related NP hard problem somewhere. I tried to find the specific problem later but I didn't succeed. Maybe there is no better option than just trying all different possible basis? In this case, is there a related NP hard problem?

---

##### What I already tried

One immediate idea I had, was selecting the basis, where the total component sum (so $\sum_{i=1}^r\sum_{j=1}^n (\vec b_i)_j$) is minimal. But this will not work. Here is a counterexample: Let $\vec a_1 := (1, 5)^\top$, $\vec a_2 := (0, 1)^\top$ and $\vec a_3 := (3, 9)^\top$. Any pair of these 3 vectors would yield a basis. So let's select the ones where the component sum is the smallest. These are $\vec a_2$ (component sum $0+1=1$) and $\vec a_1$ (component sum $1+5=6$). As it is a basis of $\mathbb{N}^2$ the coefficients are unique. You can quickly see that $-6\vec a_2 + 3\vec a_1 = \vec a_3$. Here, the coefficients sum up to $-6 + 3 = -3$ which is clearly less than 1. But you can reach a positive sum, by selecting $\vec a_2$ and $\vec a_3$ instead, as $2\vec a_2 + \frac{1}{3}\vec a_3 = \vec a_1$ and clearly $2 + \frac{1}{3} \geq 1$. How would know to choose $\vec a_2$ and $\vec a_3$ a priori?

---

##### Edit

I've generated 1000 matrices randomly and found that for every of those matrices, such a basis could be selected. Thus I assume, that this basis always exists, but why? And more importantly, how would you figure it out.

By a similar experiment I also found that at least one of the possible basis always include the vector with the smallest component sum. There are sometimes other basis with this property not including this "smallest" vector, but there is always at least one.

Comment: Do you want the basis to be in the span of the $a_i$ or in the set?

Comment: The basis' span should be the same as the span of the vectors $\vec a_j$. But I don't want to create a totally new basis out of thin air for this span but select a maximally independent set of these original vectors to be the basis. Thus
$\operatorname{span}(\vec a_1, \dots, \vec a_n) = \operatorname{span}(\vec b_1, \dots, \vec b_r)$, $\vec b_1, \dots, \vec b_r \in \{\vec a_1, \dots, \vec a_n\}$ and $\vec b_1, \dots, \vec b_r$ are linearly independent.
I hope I made it clear now

Comment: This seems trickier than it initially appears. I hope you get some good responses.

Comment: Given the example, it seems that $0\in\Bbb N$ for the OP; in that case, we need to assume that none of the $\vec a_j$ equals $\vec 0$.

Comment: @GregMartin You are right. This assumption is missing. I'll add this. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\vec v_1,\dots,\vec v_r$ be a linearly independent set in $\Bbb R^n$, and let $H$ be the unique $(r-1)$-dimensional affice space passing through $\vec v_1,\dots,\vec v_r$. Then $H$ separates the $r$-dimensional subspace span$(\vec v_1,\dots,\vec v_r)$ into two open half-spaces: one piece $S_0$ contains the origin and the other piece $S_1$ does not.

The crucial observation is that if $\vec y = \sum_{i=1}^r \lambda_i \vec v_i$ is any vector in span$(\vec v_1,\dots,\vec v_r)$, then
$$
\sum_{i=1}^r \lambda_i < 1 \text{ if and only if } \vec y \in S_0.
$$

Therefore I believe this procedure always works:

- Let $C$ be the convex hull of the vectors $\vec a_1, \dots, \vec a_m$, and let $r$ be the dimension of $C$. Each highest-dimensional face of this convex hull is an $(r-1)$-dimensional simplex determined by $r$ of the vectors $\vec a_1, \dots, \vec a_m$. (We allow degenerately neighbouring faces, such as collinear edges, coplanar $2$-dimensional faces, etc.)
- $C$ does not contain the origin; therefore there exists a highest-dimension face which divides span$(\vec a_1, \dots, \vec a_m)$ into two pieces, one of which contains the origin and the other of which contains (the interior of) $C$. This highest-dimensional face is determined by some subset $\{\vec b_1,\dots,\vec b_r\}$ of $\{\vec a_1, \dots, \vec a_m\}$. (There may be many such faces, but there is always at least one.)
- These vectors $\vec b_1,\dots,\vec b_r$ are the ones we seek, by the crucial observation above.

Comment: Wow, this answer is super impressive. Thanks a lot. But as I see it, there is still one thing missing. We now know that this face exists. But how can we find it? Or is there something I don't see? But the refrasing in terms of geometry, already shines a totally different light on the problem. Thanks again :)

Comment: Okay, there is a simple way. Any ray cast from the origin and intersecting the convex hull will hit the convex hull at a face, that matches this criteria. By the convexity of the hull, it will always be "behind" this face and as the whole ray (including the origin) up to the intersection point was "infront" of that face, this face indeed seperates the whole space in a part, where the origin is and another where the convex hull is in. But maybe there is a smarter way...

Comment: I thought about such a ray in my proof (eventually decided it wasn't needed there), so I think that's a good idea. By the way, this proof can be extended to show that the vector with smallest component sum can always be included: just slide the hyperplane $x_1+\cdots+x_n=0$ in the direction $(1,\dots,1)$—the first place where it intersects $C$ will be precisely that vector.

Comment: That makes sense. The problem actually continues with selecting one specific basis. The crazy thing is, that finding this basis now just corresponds with sending a specific ray from the origin and seeing what face of the convex hull it collides with. So thank you again for the geometric intuition. The whole solution couldn't have been more beautiful.